# What do these traffic signs mean? I saw them in Bali, Indonesia

Tags: indonesia, traffic, road-signs

What do these traffic signs mean? I saw them in Bali, Indonesia.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

These are road classifications meant for truck drivers, in terms of max dimensions and weight of the vehicles allowed.

**Sign with one line:** Entry restrictions on vehicles with a width exceeding 2.5 meters, length exceeding 18 meters, height 4.2 meters, and the heaviest axle load of 10 tons.

**Sign with two lines:** Entry restrictions on vehicles with a width exceeding 2.5 meters, length exceeding 12 meters, height 4.2 meters, and the heaviest axle load of 8 tons.

**Sign with three lines:** Entry restrictions on vehicles with a width exceeding 2.1 meters, length exceeding 9 meters, height 3.5 meters, and the heaviest axle load of 8 tons.

[Source (page 82, in Indonesian)](https://slideplayer.info/slide/13951609/)

Comment: I consider these as the most boring, misleading and ugly road signs ever..

Comment: Strangely, page 82 seems to have a misprint. Instead of pictures of signs I, II and III, it has pictures of signs I, II and II.

Comment: @WeatherVane the third line is there, it's just formatted badly, look at the line under.

Comment: Hah! Printed over the next sign down!

Comment: @NeanDerThal how are they ugly or misleading? They may just not be very descriptive for foreigners, not for the truck drivers who now the class of their vehicle.

Comment: @PHPst compared to [those](https://www.google.com/search?q=weird+road+signs&source=lnms&tbm=isch) they are ugly.. just an opinion.